# TabLayout with rounded corder first and last

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have created `TabLayout` in my `Android` application. I want to make like following image.

[image]

**My Code:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            >

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  
/>
```

To give rounded corner on start and end I have created the following xml:

**tab_rounded_corner.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

        <solid android:color="@color/color_common_header" />

    </shape>

</item>
<item>

    <shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

        <solid android:color="@color/color_white" />

    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

To give that style I have used the following:

```
mTabLayout.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_rounded_corner);
```

I works fine. But when selecting tab's, it will not set selected and unselected colour.

[image]

Edit:

This is how i can get after giving. But still not proper.

```
app:tabBackground="@drawable/rounded_corner_button"
```

**rounded_corner_button.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/color_common_header" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/color_white"/>
</selector>
```

[image]

How can I get selected colour?

Comment: Hi. Ketan so do you need the first image you posted ?

Comment: @Piyush Yes. exactly. I have made both side corner radios but selected color is not working

Comment: So did you make both selector in different file?

Comment: @Piyush no i ahve made one selector to made them rounded like in question. tab_rounded_corner.xml

Comment: Try to make two different. One for white and one for selected color.

Comment: @Piyush But i have given resource file like. `getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable` Which property i have to use for selected?

Comment: @Piyush whole line. `mTabLayout.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_rounded_corner);`